# How choose which android api level to load in sdk and how supporting older versions work: working with apache cordova

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

Sorry if this is a too easy question. I'm a long time web developer and now trying to carry my experience to mobile platforms through cordova. I've installed android sdk manager but don't know which api versions to include. My question is, does latest api version have also support for older versions? Do I need to include all other versions for my app to be able work on those older versions? And where do android sdk apis fit in cordova? How should I compile for the release?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see too many sub questions in a single question. To answer your question in short, you can install the latest version of android sdk which in turn supports older versions too.

The best place for you to start in understanding these concepts relative to Cordova is the [official documentation link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) This links should answer almost all your questions. Hope it helps. Cheers